# typeorm: how to query and left join with certain columns in the left table as new key-value pairs in the result?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have the following `User` and `OrganizationUser` entities, linked by "One to Many" and "Many To One" relation: one row in `User` can correspond to many rows in `OrganizationUser`; and multiple rows in `OrganizationUser` can have the same `userId`, pointing to one unique row in `User`:

Entity `User`:

```
@Entity()
class User extends BaseEntity {
  static validations = {
    name: [is.required(), is.maxLength(100)],
    email: [is.required(), is.email(), is.maxLength(200)],
  };

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  email: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => OrganizationUser,
    organizationUser => organizationUser.user,
    {cascade: true}
  )
  organizationUser: OrganizationUser[]

}
```

Entity `OrganizationUsers`:

```
class OrganizationUser extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Organization, 
    organization => organization.organizationUsers
  )
  organization: Organization;

  @Column('integer')
  organizationId: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => User, 
    user => user.organizationUser
  )
  user: User;

  @Column('integer')
  userId: number;
  
  @Column('integer', {nullable: true})
  quota: number | null;

  @Column('integer', {nullable: true})
  used: number | null;
```

Now I can use the following methods to get all rows given an `organizationId`:

```
  const org_users = await getRepository(OrganizationUser)
    .find({ organizationId : req.currentOrganization.id });
```

or:

```
  const org_users = await createQueryBuilder("OrganizationUser")
  .where("OrganizationUser.organizationId = :oid", { oid:  req.currentOrganization.id})
  .getMany();
```

and the results are:

```
    "org_users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 10,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0
        },
         
       ...
```

However, I want to add a new key-value pare in the result:

```
    "org_users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alice",  // newly added
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob",  // newly added
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 10,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0
        },
         
       ...
```

How can I modify my typeorm query to achieve this goal?

UPDATE:
I tried:

```
  const org_users = await createQueryBuilder("OrganizationUser")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("OrganizationUser.user", "user", "OrganizationUser.userId = user.id")
  .addSelect(['user.name'])
  .where("OrganizationUser.organizationId = :oid", { oid:  req.currentOrganization.id})
  .getMany();
```

which gives:

```
    "org_users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Alice",
                "email": "Alice@app",
                "uuid": "d152894b-5eca-46aa-ab96-bc39504045da",
                "createdAt": "2021-07-24T10:01:20.490Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-07-24T10:01:20.490Z"
            }
        },
```

Which I do not like, because it is too much info.

Also I tried:

```
  const org_users = await createQueryBuilder("OrganizationUser")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("OrganizationUser.user", "user", "OrganizationUser.userId = user.id")
  .select(['OrganizationUser.userId', 'OrganizationUser.organizationId', 
           'OrganizationUser.used', 'OrganizationUser.quota', 'user.name']) 
  .where("OrganizationUser.organizationId = :oid", { oid:  req.currentOrganization.id})
  .getMany();
```

Which gives a result I can take:

```
    "org_users": [
        {
            "organizationId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "quota": 10,
            "used": 0,
            "user": {
                "name": "Alice"
            }
        },
```

However, it is too silly to do `.select(['OrganizationUser.userId', 'OrganizationUser.organizationId', 'OrganizationUser.used', 'OrganizationUser.quota', 'user.name'])` .

Such a lone line. What if in another situation I want more columns from both main table and the left table?

It would be crazy to manually write all column names.

Is there a way to include all columns in main table by default and specify the wanted columns in left table?